# Google Apps Script Libraries no longer linking

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have 3 Google Apps Scripts which I'm trying to allow to talk to each other through the library option, but I haven't managed to get it to work. At one point I had 2 linked and it worked, and then I decided to split one script into 2, but now the libraries aren't working and I feel like I'm missing something obvious.

[image: Libraries]

The SendToSlack and EmployeeList libraries are listed in the third script and it looks fine. I've then tried to call these with:

`// this one is in an external JS file`

`google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(populateNamesList).EmployeeList.getNames();`

`// this one is in a GS file as standard`

`SendToSlack.initalise(chan, botName, message, iconEmoji);`

This code worked before. Now when I load the page I get the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getNames' of undefined
```

And when I click a button to activate the second line, I get:

```
Uncaught  at userClicked
```

I think the code is correct but I've somehow broken the libraries?

Edit: The autocomplete in the online IDE even works. So I'm pretty sure the code is correct. I don't understand why it doesn't work when published.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using [google.script.run](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run#myFunction(...)) you can execute any **function** defined in your server-side Apps Script. From the documentation:

> Executes the server-side Apps Script function with the corresponding name.

However, you cannot specify any variable as you are doing. The functions must be declared on the global scope of the script so that they can be ran. In this case, if you want to call the function `getNames()` accessible through the `EmployeeList` global object, you should create a global function in your script that encapsulates the call. For instance:

*Code.gs*

```js
function getEmployeeNames() {
  return EmployeeList.getNames();
}
```

*Page.html*

```html
...
<script>
google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(populateNamesList).getEmployeeNames();
</script>
...
```